# Gradle build error: Gradle DSL method not found: 'uildscript()'

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Hey I am getting this error while running the app. Please can someone tell me how to fix it?

> Error:(1, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'uildscript()' Possible
>   causes:
>
> The project 'ePulse2' may be using a version of Gradle
>   that does not contain the method. Open
>   Gradle wrapper file
>
> The build file may be missing a Gradle
>   plugin. Apply Gradle plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo: change `uildscript` to `buildscript`. [Here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#buildscript(groovy.lang.Closure)) are the docs.